# Why did RFC 4158 (Path Building) restrict Trust Anchors to self-signed certificates?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, x.509, rfc

I'm having trouble using Wget to download a file over HTTPS from `ftp.gnu.org` using the *Let's Encrypt X3* root. The *Let's Encrypt X3* is cross-certified, which means it has an issuer and its not self-signed. When using *Let's Encrypt X3*, Wget is failing with the error it can't find the issuer certificate even though I am trying to root trust in the Let's Encrypt certificate.

I visited [RFC 4158, Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure: Certification Path Building](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4158) to see what the behavior should be. The document discusses in detail building paths from end-entity or subscriber certificates to CA roots and trust anchors. Its what one would expect.

However, [Section 1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4158#section-1.3) provides terminology, and it defines trust anchors:

- **Trust List**: A list of trust anchors.
- **Trust Anchor**: The combination of a trusted public key and the name of the entity to which the corresponding private key belongs.
- **Trust Anchor Certificate**: A self-signed certificate for a trust anchor that is used in certification path processing.
- *"Trust Anchor Certificate"* and the definition that demands *"self-signed"* means we cannot root trust in a subordinate certificate, like the *Let's Encrypt X3* root that's been cross-certified.

My question is, why did the RFC do that? Why are we forced to use a self-signed certificate as an anchor, and include unneeded portions of the PKI that only serve to complicate path building and increase attack surface?

Comment: According to [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) the X3 certificates aren't roots but are intermediates, signed by the X1 root and an ISRG root.  That doesn't answer your question about the RFC, of course :-)

Comment: Related to but not answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398167/wget-cannot-validate-https-ftp-gnu-org . Note that roots are conventionally defined to be selfsigned; if an anchor is (allowed to be) not selfsigned then it is not a root (but is an anchor).

Comment: Could you add the error message from wget? (I suspect that we're dealing with a very specific wget issue here and not a general PKI issue.)

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those tricky subtle wordings. The full meaning of the RFC may not be obvious on the first reading. From your question (*emphasis mine*):

> **Trust Anchor**: The combination of a *trusted public key* and the name of the entity to which the corresponding private key belongs.
>   **Trust Anchor Certificate**: A *self-signed certificate* for a trust anchor that is used in certification path processing.

A trust store serves two purposes:

1. Establish that all signatures generated by this public key should be trusted, and
2. Bind the public key to a name (usually an LDAP Distinguished Name (DN) is defined in [RFC2253](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt))

Some corollaries of that are:

- All signature performed by that key will be trusted, including certificate issuances.
- Because you are explicitly marking it as Trusted, This key can not be revoked through normal methods - the only way is to manually remove it from your trust store.

---

The subtly here is that the RFC allows you to pin *either* a certificate, *or* a public key directly, however *if* you pin a certificate then it needs to be a root certificate. The RFC gives some justification here:

> 1.5.1.  Hierarchical Structures
>
> A hierarchical PKI, depicted in Figure 1, is one in which all of the
>      end entities and relying parties use a single "Root CA" as their
>      trust anchor.

From the CA's point of view, they may not want you pinning the intermediate CA because that removes their ability to revoke it if it becomes compromised: even if they publish a revocation for it, your client will ignore it.

In the case where a CA does want you to be able to use an intermediate CA as a trust anchor, I have seen them give a trust anchor *both* an issued certificate, *and* a self-signed cert for the same public key and DN. I would assume that Let's Encrypt does not do this for its intermediate CAs.

---

As to your actual question about `wget`, `ftp.gnu.org`, and the `Let's Encrypt X3` intermediate CA, I think you have two options:

- Find the self-signed root cert that issued `Let's Encrypt X3` and add that to your trust store.
- Figure out how to pin a public key directly. This will depend on the software / OS stack you're using and whether it supports the archaic and uncommon part of the RFC that allows a Trust Anchor to be a key and not a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

As a general assumption:  if it's not self-signed; you're relying on some other entity to imbue trust; that other entity by definition becomes the anchor.

Though many implementations may trust something further down the chain, that isn't a function of PKI/x509 - it's an out-of-band trust; thus out-of-scope for the RFC.

It raises a question:  why would you imbue implicit trust in an anchor, that itself doesn't have implicit trust from its issuer (it could be revoked)